# prerender-spa-plugin shows 2 pages on one route, instead of only one, in quasar framework, vue 1.x

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to configure `prerender-spa-plugin` to work with my vue.js (1.x) application. When I build an application without it - everything works perfectly, but I need to get pages pre rendered foe SEO purposes.

When I install the plugin, it does prerender, but then it shows me some router error (`[vue-router] Uncought error during transition` ) and also `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's(e).isEqualNode')`.
Again - none of this errors happen if I build the app for production without `pretender-spa-plugin`.

Some info about the tools:

```
- Mac OS
- node v6.10.1
- quasar --version 0.5.2 (project runs using quasar framework)
- npm -v3.10.10
- vue.js (1.x)
```

Then, relevant settings are:

#### webpack.prod.conf.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
  new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
    // Absolute path to compiled SPA
    path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    // List of routes to prerender
    [ '/',  '/apps'],
    {
       captureAfterDocumentEvent: 'custom-post-render-event',
       captureAfterTime: 2000,
       ignoreJSErrors: false,
       captureAfterElementExists: '.main',
    } 
  )
 ]
```

div `.main` actually exists within every component which I need to prerender

#### main.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  Quasar.start(() => {
    Router.start(App, '#quasar-app')
  })
  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('custom-post-render-event'))
})
```

#### app.vue

```
module.exports = {
  replace: false,
  ....
```

### What I've already tried:

1. Not to use some of these triggers, which I've written here foe webpack. I guess I've already tried all possible combinations - sometimes build process just hangs up, sometimes - it is compiled with the same problem.
2. I tried to set this custom even in my initial app.vue file, and attach it to `ready ()` - the same result
3. I tried to specify `replace: false` to all inner components too - and again, the same result - it just always gives me the router error, and then shows index page rendered on every route (together with content which should be there)
4. The only thing which 'helped' - is not to specify `/` route for the plugin. Then, My index component is not pre rendered, and all others work in a good order. But obviously I'll need to have it pre rendered too.

Any help or suggestions highly welcomed! Maybe, I'm missing something `quasar framework` specific?

I'm also using `html-webpack-plugin`, can it be because of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem appeared to be in the `vue-helmet` plugin. I'm not sure why, but before I installed prerender in was working all good (`vue-helment` is used to manage metadata on separate pages). But when used together - they are making conflicts. 
So, I had just find another solution for managing metadata, which also works with pre rendering. 
Now, everything is fine

Comment: What's the solution you found ?